# OpenNI: Device not found in sample code even though it is detected and working

Tags: openni, asus-xtion

I want to run the OpenNI 2 code samples with my new Asus Xtion 2 camera on Windows 10 (64 bit), but the device doesn't get found. What's bizarre is that I can execute the pre-compiled binaries of the samples and see the signal streams in NiViewer without any problem, but when I try to run the samples by compiling the source code in Visual Studio 2017 the camera is not detected. Specifically, `rc` in the following initialization code

```
Status rc = OpenNI::initialize();
Device device;
rc = device.open(ANY_DEVICE);
if (rc != STATUS_OK)
{
    printf("Couldn't open device\n%s\n", OpenNI::getExtendedError());
    return 2;
}
[...]
```

does not return `STATUS_OK` and `getExtendedError()` returns a no device found error upon execution.

I have only one OpenNI installation on my PC so there can't be any confusion between multiple versions.

What could that error be due to?

Answer (score 1):

You need put RvcLib.dll and SenDuck.dll into build_path\OpenNI2\Drivers.

Both files can find in Tools\OpenNI2\Drivers.